# Opencv conflicting version for C++

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I seem to be in a spot of bother with multiple versions of opencv installed maybe. I plan to use opencv with C++. (Due to good use of virtual environments, opencv in different Python envs all work fine)

When I run the command `pkg-config --cflags opencv`, it gives

```
-I/usr/include/opencv
```

Upon running a C++ code to check the version using `CV_VERSION`, I get `3.2.0`. I wanted to install contrib modules as well for C++.

However, upon navigating to `/usr/include`, I find another folder with the name `opencv2`, where the additional features are present such as `flann.hpp`, `rgbd.hpp` and their folders, which I presume are the opencv contrib ones. (I think these correspond to version `4.1.2`)

Interestingly, when I check `/usr/local/lib`, I find various `libopencv` `.so` files of version `4.1.2`

Hence, I am guessing that `opencv 4` is installed in my system with the contrib modules, but for some reason it cant find it. How do I set my default path to this?
What do I do to solve the mess that is here.

Thanks

Edit: The `home/username/opencv/build/lib` also has `libopencv` `.so` files with version `4.1.2`. So my custom installation is this. I presume my issue is just to make the default c++ opencv directory to point to this, but I am not so sure if that is the case and how to do it.

Comment: What do command  `opencv_version` give you ? That is how you could find opencv  version on your system.

Comment: It gives ```4.1.2```

Comment: Then your default CV version must be `4.1.2` .

Comment: But as I mentioned in the question, when a C++ code is compiled with ```pkg-config --cflags opencv```, it gives the version as ```3.1.2```, and thus when I try to compile a huge opencv project with xfeatures.hpp, it fails to find the package as Cmake points to this

Comment: How did you installed opencv..? via apt or you compiled it from source code ?

Comment: Hello sorry, apologies for the late reply. I compiled it from source

Comment: Have you tried `sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf' `and `sudo ldconfig ` after `sudo make install`

Comment: Hey @anoopknr yes I did that. I have kind of solved the issue but not entirely. In all my CMake files I have specified the versions for finding Opencv as 4, and that way, my desired opencv version is picked up. So I suppose I can live with it